# Android - How to know, in the host activity, the navigation has come to end

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm thinking about a new architecture for my application
and I'm implementing something new to an app that already exists.

So, basically my new module has a flow, using navigation component, and when this comes to end my app need to know to call the old flow.

How do I know that?
Can host activity knows when navigation end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your host activity can call `addOnDestinationChangedListener` so that it is aware of the current fragment in the navigation flow. If my understanding is correct, you could do something like this in your host activity's onCreate:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
           @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
       // if you have reached the end of your navigation flow, do something
       if(destination.getId() == R.id.end_dest) {
           // add code calling your old flow here
       } 
   }
});
```